# Check if a layout exsists in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I have in String name of layout:

```
String l_name = "fragment_item_detail";
```

I want to check if this layout exsist (check if isset R.layout.fragment_item_detail) and get this int id.
How can do it?

Comment: Why would you need this? You're writing the app, you should know what layouts you put in it!

Comment: you can check if a view is visible, is that something like what you need?

Comment: i want do this, because i have menu with a lot of positions. Every position on this menu have own layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following sample code (if you're inside an Activity):

```
boolean layoutExists = getResources().getIdentifier(l_name, "layout", getPackageName()) != 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int layoutId = 0;

try {
   Class res = R.layout.class;
   Field field = res.getField( l_name );
   layoutId = field.getInt(null);
}
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```